# Adding forms in non-form pages in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to add a simple select box and submit button to a "show" page in ActiveAdmin. Basically, the clients wants a simple way to assign a currently unassigned widget to the item currently being viewed. Not that that really matters.

What I am seeing is that although I can add a form and a select box, if I try to add anything after the select, the select doesn't get displayed. It's not that it is hidden by CSS, but that it just doesn't render.

Here's the relevant code:

```
column do
  panel "Devices without locations" do
    devices = Device.without_location
    form_tag add_device_admin_location_path do 
      select_tag(:device_id, options_from_collection_for_select(devices, :id, :name))
      submit_tag
    end
  end
end
```

The submit tag will be displayed, but the select will not. event if I put "foo" in there, only the "foo" will show up. The only time the select will show up is if there is nothing else in the block.

**Update:**
Okay, so I've been able to work around this by concatenating the output together. It's not ideal, and I definitely feel dirty, but it works.

I tried using formtastic on this, but it appears to only accepts attributes from the model, this doesn't work: I'm updating the device, not the location.

This works, but if anyone has a more better way of doing this, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue, and moving form into app/views/admin/#{model_name}s/_#{partial_name}.html.erb worked for me fine